# cancel order from customer feature in nopcommerce

Tags: nopcommerce, orders

I am a newbie to nopcommerce 2.2 which uses mvc framework. In nopcommerce admin backend,there is option for admin to cancel the order. Then the mail goes to the customer saying that his order has been cancelled. I wanted to have the cancel order feature for customer,wherin he can cancel the order placed in his myaccount/orders tab.But the order should only be cancelled after the mail goes to the admin and he approves the cancellation.After the mail is sent to the admin,it should wait for admin's approval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're up for coding it because that functionality doesn't exist right now.

- Add a "Cancel Order" button to the Order Details page if the order status is not Completed
- Add a column to the Order table to indicate that a cancellation was requested.
- Send an email to the store owner if the Cancel button is clicked by the customer
- Add a field to the Admin/Order/Edit/ screen to show the customer wants to cancel.
- The store owner clicks the Cancel Order button that is already there.